# Parse UTC date time with angular-moment2

Tags: datetime, angular2-moment

I have basically a date '2017-08-03T05:46:35.046328Z' & I want to parse this using angular 2 - moment in this format 'MM/DD/YYYY 12.00AM/PM.

Answer (score 1):

```
moment('2017-08-03T05:46:35.046328Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a')
```

I hope you have managed to include `angular-moment` into your project.